# Method to limit total number of child + grandchild records

Tags: validation, roll-up-summary

I have a Master object object called `Application__c` and the child object is `Credit__c` .

I have another object called `Credit_Plan__c` ,which is the child object of `Credit__c`.

(`Application__c` <=== `Credit__c` <=== `Credit_Plan__c`)

Under Child object (`Credit__c`), I have three record types. For these three three record types, I am creating multiple `Credit_Plan__c` records .

For ex : Under `Application__c`, I have created 3 `Credit__c` object records ( Total under single `Application__c`: 3)

Under `Credit__c` object, I have created 3 record types (Credit A , Credit B , Credit C)

1. For the first record type Credit A, I have created 2 `Credit_Plan__c` records
2. For the second record type Credit B, I have created 2 `Credit_Plan__c` records
3. For the third record type Credit C, I have created 1 `Credit_Plan__c` record

So Total, 3 `Credit__c` records and 5 `Credit_Plan__c` records (Total 3 + 5 = 8) under `Application__c` object .

I want to add the validation "Please enter no more than 10 Credits"

I have created roll up summary on `Credit__c` object to calculate the count of credit records in the master `Application__c` object .
And also created roll up summary on `Credit_Plan__c` object to calculate the count of credit plan records in the master `Credit__c` object.

Roll up summary count for `Credit__c` which is created on `Application__c` object is working but roll up summary count for `Credit_Plan__c` which is created on `Credit__c` object, it is showing the count for individual records

for ex : Credit A : 3, Credit B : 3, Credit C : 1

I want to get total records created on Application object

Comment: I've taken the liberty of editing your question title, because saying things like "Urgent" tends to attract negative attention (and tends to be a marker of lower-quality questions that are lacking in detail). I've also edited the body of your question to make things a bit more clear, and to make better use of some of the "markdown" formatting options.

Comment: Overall, I think this question has a good level of detail, especially for a first question. "Urgent" aside, I don't think this question deserves the negative attention it has gotten, so I'll upvote it to offset part of that.

Comment: I think that there's one key piece of information missing here. How many rollup summary fields do you have on `Credit__c` that summarize `Credit_Plan__c`? The way you've presented your question makes it sound like you have 3 separate rollup summary fields on `Credit__c` here (one for each of your 3 record types). When you come back to this question, please [edit] it to add this clarification.

Comment: As i Said before 
1)Application is the Master Object of Credit__c 
2) Credit__c is the Master Object of Credit_Plan__c.
3)On Application Object , i have one Roll up Summary 
  Field name is Credit_Count__c (Roll-Up Summary (COUNT Credit))
4)On Credit__c Object , I have one Roll up Summary
Field name is No_of_Credit_Plans__c(Roll-Up Summary (COUNT Credit Plan)
5)For Credit__c object I have Created three record types ,for each record type we have defined different fields using the layout .
  For these three records types ,we have a related list called "Credit_Plan__c" object

Comment: 6)Lets Say the record type names for the Credit Object are 
a) Credit A
b) Credit B
C) Credit C
6) For the above three record types we have defined different fields 
7) If i create the record for the above  each record type , the count of Credit is 3 (its working) ,because we are using the roll up summary on Application object

Comment: 8) If i Create the one Credit_Plan__c record On Credit A 
   if  I create the one  Credit_Plan__c record on Credit B
  if  I Create the one  credit_plan__c record on Credit C
  So Total Credit Records are 3 and Total Credit plan records are 3 
  So Total records of Credit and Credit Plan are 6
9) I have no issues with Credit Count but when I want the total count of Credit plan on Application object ,it is not displaying 3 ,it is displaying count for each record type as 1 1 1 not 3

Comment: Your three comments here are an example of things that should be included in your original question by making an [edit].

Answer (score -2, accepted):

**Solution** :

Now I am able to get the total count of Credit and Credit Plan using the AggregateResult function, please find the below code

```
List<AggregateResult> groupedResults = [select Count(Application__r.Credit_Count__c) plan,SUM(No_of_Credit_Plans__c) aver from Credit__c where Application__c = :appId];
        Object creditplan = groupedResults[0].get('plan');
        Object creditCount = groupedResults[0].get('aver');               
        //countOne = (integer)groupedResults.get('plan');
        //countTwo = (integer)groupedResults.get('aver');             
        TotalCount = (integer)creditplan + (Decimal)creditCount;
        if (TotalCount > 20 )
        {
         // Error Message 
        }
```

Comment: I've downvoted this answer because it is a "code dump" (code with no explanation of what it does or how it works). The purpose of this site isn't just to help you overcome your own problems. Questions and answers are meant to also help _other people_ with similar problems. To that end, a "good" answer will typically explain _what_ the initial issue was, _why_ it was an issue, _how_ to fix it, and _why_ the fix works.

Answer (score 1):

### What you have so far

What follows is a best attempt, given the information provided at time of writing.

Based on that, I think your schema looks something like this:
[image]

- `Credit_Plan__c` has a master-detail relationship field that points to `Credit__c`
- `Credit__c` has a master-detail relationship field that points to `Application__c`

I also think that, based on your description, you have 3 rollup fields on `Credit__c` to give you the number of `Credit_Plan__c` records of each of your 3 record types.

### A solution

My schema has probably already ruined the surprise for some of the people reading this, but the key to success here is to aggregate the data stored in the `Number_of_Plan_A__c`, `Number_of_Plan_B__c`, `Number_of_Plan_C__c` fields (on `Credit__c` into a single number so that we can roll it up to the `Application__c` level.

To do this, I'm simply using a formula field (`Total_Plans__c` on the `Credit__c` object). The formula itself is simple

```
`Number_of_Plan_A__c` + `Number_of_Plan_B__c` + `Number_of_Plan_C__c`
```

### Why it works (and a workaround)

What might be surprising here is the fact that **we can use formula fields in a rollup-summary field**. Formula fields can be rolled up as long as they aren't pulling any cross-object data. So, if your formula (let's call it `Formula_1__c`) doesn't contain any dots/periods/full-stops, and any other formula fields that are referenced (directly or indirectly) by `Formula_1__c` don't contain any dots/periods/full-stops as well, then you can use it in a rollup summary field.

If you *do* reference cross-object data, you can still cause the data to be able to be rolled-up, but doing so involves making a second field, and a workflow rule + field update action to take the value of your first field (that can't be rolled up) and put it into your second field (which can be rolled up).

### I cheated (just a little)

Ok, so I wasn't entirely honest in my solution. My `Total_Plans__c` formula field actually is the sum of `Number_of_Plan_A__c`, `Number_of_Plan_B__c`, `Number_of_Plan_C__c`, *and adds 1 to that number to account for the `Credit__c` record itself*

This allows us to use a single rollup field on `Application__c` to count the total number of Credits + Credit Plans. Following your example, let's say that you have the following Credit and Credit Plan record distribution

- Test Credit 1 has 2 Credit Plans of type A, and one of type B
- Test Credit 2 has 1 Credit Plan of type B, and one of type C
- Test Credit 3 has no Credit Plans

Then `Total_Plans__c` would be...

- 4 on Test Credit 1 (2 plans of A, 1 plan of B, and 1 for the credit itself)
- 3 on Test Credit 2 (1 plan of B, 1 plan of C, and 1 for the credit itself)
- 1 on Test Credit 3 (no plans, just 1 for the credit itself)

Rolling that up in `Application__c` gives you the desired total of 8

You could absolutely just have `Total_Plans__c` reflect the number of `Credit_Plan__c` records for each `Credit__c`, have two rollup fields on `Application__c` (one to count number of credits, one to sum the total number of plans on each credit), and have your validation rule sum those two rollups together...but we're limited as to the number of rollup summary fields we can create on each object. The choice of how exactly you want to proceed is up to you.

### About that validation rule

At this point, I hope that the validation rule itself is simple enough for you to work out on your own.

I will, however, say that this validation rule will work to prevent the number of Credits + Credit Plans from exceeding your specified value. If a given `Application__c` record is at a total count of 8, and you try to add 3 `Credit_Plan__c` records through something like the Apex Dataloader, Salesforce will prevent those records from being inserted.

This works because of [the order of execution](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_triggers_order_of_execution.htm)

Specifically, because of step 16

> 16. If the record contains a roll-up summary field or is part of a cross-object workflow, performs calculations and updates the roll-up summary field in the parent record. Parent record goes through save procedure.

Inserting a `Credit_Plan__c` record will cause `Credit__c` to undergo a save procedure, which in turn will cause `Application__c` to undergo a save procedure, which means the validation rules on `Application__c` will be evaluated.

This is nice in this specific case, but be aware that the error messages that are produced as a result are not user-friendly. These implicit interactions between objects also means that you'll need to be more mindful of the amount and type of work that you're doing in the triggers for `Credit__c` and `Credit_Plan__c` so you don't run into governor limits (but that topic is out-of-scope for this question, and could be a book in and of itself).